# Is Badlands unique or are there similar parks to go Dinosaur fossil hunting?

Tags: children, activities, national-parks, south-dakota

Thinking of taking my kid on to look at some fossils.  I am definitely planning a visit to the [Badlands](http://www.nps.gov/badl/forkids/index.htm) to go dinosaur bone hunting but are there other parks or places similar to this?

Comment: What a cool thing to do with your kid!

Comment: well, there is the Alberta Badlands :-) http://www.albertatravel.org/Badlands_Alberta.htm

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by "fossil hunting"? It doesn't sound so in your question, but when I read the title, I first thought of parks that allow you (or, well, mainly children) to dig through piles and piles of pebbles, a few of which might contain small fossilized prehistoric animals (like [Holzmaden in Germany](http://www.urweltsteinbruch.de/)).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I mean that: http://blackhillsvisitor.com/featured-articles.html?pid=879&sid=1645:Fossils-of-the-Badlands

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not the scale of the Badlands, only a small museum, there is [Dinosauria](http://www.dinosauria.org/) Museum in the South-West of France, somewhere between Carcassonne and Perpignan in a small village named Espéraza.

Near that place there is another museum dedicated to the [Tautavel Man](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautavel_man).

This region on the foothills of the Pyrénées mountains is also full of medieval Cathar castles.

Comment: This looks great.